# Visual Studio publish ignores .js files in Views folder, for .NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, publish

Here's the steps:

1. Create a simple project using **ASP.NET Core Web Application** template
2. Publish it without modifying anything, to a folder

If `Views` folder is not in the published output, it's because your version of .NET Core compiles views by default. Simply add this to your `.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And publish again.

1. Now add a `Home.js` file to `Views/Default` folder
2. Publish again to a folder
3. As you can see, `Home.cshtml` is published to the output folder, but `Home.js` is not.

What's wrong here? This makes our deployment engine inefficient and we need to manually keep `.js` files in sync.

Comment: static files should go in your `wwwroot` or equivalent

Comment: The Views folder is not for static files. Use the `wwwroot` folder or you will need to manually tell the deployment where the files are located

Comment: That **should go** is a should. Not a must. What if we need to have js files in `Views` folder. Generally speaking, what if we have static files all over different folders and places in a project? What configuration should we do to make them also get published to the output directory?

Answer (score 4):

Conventions are followed for a reason. It promotes good app design. Having static files littered all over you project *is not good app design*. Still, you are correct that ASP.NET Core is configurable and can be made to do whatever you want to do with it, good or bad.

You've actually got two issues here: 1) files in the `Views` directory are not included in the publish and 2) the `Views` directory is not *served*. Even if you are successful including the static files in the publish, it's a pyrrhic victory, as you won't actually be able to utilize those files in your web pages.

There's no way that I'm aware of to cause an entire directory to be copied to output via the UI - only individual files. However, by editing your project file, you can add something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\**\*.js" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

That then just leaves you with the issue of actually serving these files, which becomes more problematic, as you cannot just serve some files, but only entire directories. That means potentially exposing anything in the `Views` directory. Still, if you insist:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Views")),
    RequestPath = "/Views"
});
```

Comment: Great answer. The point is I don't want to serve files. We have a home-built framework that bundles all those js files and serves them in the main page of our SPA application. We need to keep those files in `Views` folder for the sake of our file-system architecture. That is, each `js` and `css` accompanies its relevant `.cshtml` file.